# C# - FTP Upload Using UploadFileAsync With Progress on Console

Tags: c#, ftp, webclient

I'm new to C# and I wanted to do an FTP upload with progress showing on console. My code is as below from some help from MSDN examples.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FTPUpload
{
    class FTPClient
    {
        public void Upload()
        {
            string localFile = @"D:\Applications\python-3.3.0.msi";
            string destPath = "ftp://127.0.0.1/python-3.3.0.msi";

            if (File.Exists(localFile))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(localFile + " exists!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(localFile + " doesn't exists!");
            }

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Anonymous", "Anonymous");
                client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(UploadProgressCallback);
                client.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(UploadCompleted);

                client.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(destPath), localFile);

                Console.WriteLine("Upload started");
            }
        }

        public void UploadProgressCallback(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.TotalBytesToSend);
        }

        public void UploadCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Result);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            ftpClient.Upload();

        }
    }
}
```

I think I have not written it properly and I tried to search in Google can't find any examples with respect to this.

Kindly point me in right direction.

I have seen this but not able to get the point
[File is not uploaded to FTP server on some machines when using WebClient.UploadFileAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33869019/file-is-not-uploaded-to-ftp-server-on-some-machines-when-using-webclient-uploadf)

Thanks!

Comment: So what's the issue you're running into? Is it not uploading? Are you not able to connect? Are you not able to write to the console?

Comment: Console program ending without upload or printing. It is just printing "Upload Started"

Comment: There's no code to keep the console window open. Right now you attach events, then write to the console and then that's it. Program done. You gotta add some code to keep that console window alive. Console.ReadLine() or Console.ReadKey() after your  "upload started" _might_ do that, but I figure there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: @KSib what you say is works, but I just wanted to show some status and move on to another task.